# Why is it asking me for a Y position or a height? How can I fix it?

Tags: ios, autolayout, ios-autolayout

This is a very basic question and I am just not being able to fix it.

I am just trying to have two equal sized views on my scene. And I've set the constraints on both and having the:

- vertical distance between them be 0
- Both leading and trailing set at 0 with the safe areas
- Top view align top to safe area
- Bottom view align bottom to safe area

I have attached two screenshots below showing what I have:

[image]

[image]

I have also attempted to set them to equal heights

[image]

Comment: Add equal Heights constraint between these two views

Comment: "I am just trying to have two equal sized views on my scene" Then say so. However, the first thing to do is give all your Views different labels. At the moment they are called View so you can't even read the constraints.

Comment: Thank you. I tried the equal heights for the two and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @matt I got it working with PGDev's solution but I appreciate your feedback on the view labeling. I will do that in the future to make it easier to comprehend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the `constraints` you must add to both of your views.

[image]